# View is not resized onKeyboardWillShow, but onKeyboardDidShow

Tags: ionic-framework

When I click the keyboard and it opens op, the keyboard first finishes the animation. Then the view is resized. This causes for lag when the view scrolls to the field.

I have tried fixing it this way:

```
this.keyboard.onKeyboardWillShow().then(() => {
 this.content.scrollToBottom();
});
```

But because the view is not yet resized, it does not scroll. How can I fix this? The app doesn't feel native at all without this.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found for this is as follows.

I created a wrapper within my `<ion-content>`:

```
<ion-content>
 <div id="wrapper"></div>
</ion-content>
```

And styled it this way:

```
#wrapper{
 height: 100%;
 margin-bottom: 200px; /* it is best to get the keyboard height here from `onKeyboardWillShow()` */
}
```

Then in ts I did this:

```
this.keyboard.setResizeMode(KeyboardResizeMode.None);
this.keyboard.onKeyboardWillShow().subscribe(() => {
        this.content.scrollToBottom();
});
this.keyboard.onKeyboardWillHide().subscribe(() => {
        this.content.scrollToTop(500);
});
```

Works just like I want it. But I am still open to better answers.